# How incrementing the size of a queue before pushing an element to a queue gets me an error and the opposite works fine?

Tags: c, data-structures

Like I said if I put q->size++ (in push_queue function) before the if statement which contains the code of pushing an element to the queue the running of the program crashes however if I put the line after the if statement it works perfectly even though there is nothing related to the size of the queue , here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct queue_node
{
    int value;
    struct queue_node *next;
};

typedef struct queue_node queue_node;
struct queue
{
    queue_node *front ;
    queue_node *back ;
    int size;
};
typedef struct queue queue;


queue * create_queue()
{
    queue * q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
    q->back = q->front = NULL;
    q->size = 0;
    return q;
}
bool empty(queue *q)
{
    return (q->size == 0) ;
}

void push_queue(queue *q , int value)
{
    queue_node *qn = malloc(sizeof(queue_node));
    qn->next = NULL;
    qn->value = value;
    q->size++;

        if (empty(q))
    {
        q->back = q->front = qn;

    }
    else
    {
        q->back->next = qn;
        q->back = qn;

    }

}

int pop_queue(queue *q)
{
    if (empty(q))
    {
        printf("vide");
        return 0;

    }
        int value = q->front->value;
        queue_node *qn = q->front;
        q->front = q->front->next;
        free(qn);
        q->size--;
        return value;
}


int main ()
{
    queue *q = create_queue();
    push_queue(q,5);
    push_queue(q,9);
    push_queue(q,7);

    while (!empty(q))
        printf("%d\t",pop_queue(q));
    free(q);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push_queue` is first checking if the queue is empty. `empty` uses `size`. If you increment size before checking `empty`, `empty` will always be false. On the first push `q->back` will be null and `q->back->next` will segfault.

Note: since this is a [FIFO (First In First Out) queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)), "pop" is the wrong term. "push" and "pop" are associated with [stacks and LIFO queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). Consider "enqueue" and "dequeue".